# Avoiding Personal information in the JWT Token issued by Azure AD

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have been using OpenID Connect workflow with azure active directory and getting the ID token which in turn is a JWT. Decoding the JWT token i can see few personal information attributes (PII) such as firstname, lastname and email.  Is there any way to inform the Azure AD that to avoid sending these attributes as part of the JWT token.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure AD v2.0 does not include them by default. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims

Comment: We need to adhere to some PII compliance there by we can't allow this information to be present in the JWT token. Thanks for the link i will give it a try by adding optional claims to the app.

Comment: and you'll need to use Azure AD v2.0 (and we recommend you use MSAL libraries, for instance, in .NET: [MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki#conceptual-documentation))

Comment: Yes using 2.0 havent returned those claims. Thanks guys